# Sent and bounce data FTP from ET to my server?

Tags: marketing-cloud

How may I get Sent and Bounce data for my e-mail compaigns in a File(maybe CSV file) and FTP/SFTP it to my company server?

PS: we are currently doing so using API calls, but we would want to get data files, FTP them and import them to our database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to retrieve this data using a Data Tracking Extract.
[Read the following documentation](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/using_tracking_extracts/) to understand how this is possible

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Sandeep said, you will need to set up a new FTP location within your ET account, found under the Admin Tab -> Data Management -> File Locations.